# Any code points, other references on using compression and set screw fittings on same EMT run?

Tags: electrical, wiring, construction, nec

This is more a commercial/industrial electrical question, but there's no Stack for that, so;
Anyone ever been dinged by an inspector for this? I can't find anything in the 2017 or 2020 NEC, even went so far as to download NECA 1-2015, which expands on that one line from NEC 110.12 (the "neat and workmanlike manner" clause). But anyway, everywhere I look no one just outright condemns it. I found one site that mentions it but only in the vein of if you're using two different types of hardware that's more work because I guess you're loading up two different types of hardware. I'm looking at it more like, an electrician just has a few types of fittings/couplings/connectors in his pouch, so that's what he uses instead of taking the time to go get matching fittings and having a better looking run. ....then we end up with a run that maybe has set screw and standard compression couplings under an outdoor awning, then switches to raintight compression where it's exposed to the weather. (just for an example).  ...Anyway, any building pros on here know any deep-dive code points for me? (or really, any other data on this minute topic) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that all outside conduit is defined as wet, I don't get too excited about trying to seal it up tight. Don't think I've ever used compression-type - I see them mentioned as being concrete-tight without taping, which seems like a place they would save time/labor.

Answer (score 2):

NEC 110.2 you have to use [UL] approved equipment.

NEC 110.3(B) you must use equipment according to its labeling and instructions.

Any EMT couplings from competent suppliers comply with 110.2, and using them for their (one) obvious purpose satisfies 110.3(B).

Both are listed for the task, it's no worse than using different brands.